# GridView Paging and Sorting

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, paging, sqldatasource

I have a GridView webcontrol that has paging and sorting enabled. I've bound the datasource to an SqlDataSource. When I try to change the page index or sort, I get a "GridView fired event [Sorting/PageIndexChanging] which wasn't handled" error. Isn't the SqlDataSource already equipeed to handle these events?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@language = "C#" Debug="true" src="ServerCode/Default.cs" Inherits="Home.Default" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>APTEIT Data Preview</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "mainFrm" runat = "server">
        <div id = "headersDiv">
            <asp:Table id = "headerTbl" runat = "server">
            </asp:Table>
        </div>
        <div id = "dataDiv">
            <asp:GridView id = "dataTbl" runat = "server" 
                ShowHeader="false"
                AllowPaging="true"
                GridLines="None" 
                AlternatingRowStyle="altRow"
                PagerStyle="pager"
                PageSize="50"
                >
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind

```
SqlDataSource sqlData = new SqlDataSource("Hidden for security reasons");
Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
dataTbl.DataSource = sqlData;
dataTbl.DataBind();
headerTbl.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
```

Comment: FYI: "The default paging option of a data presentation control is unsuitable when working with large amounts of data, as its underlying data source control retrieves all records, even though only a subset of data is displayed. In such circumstances, we must turn to custom paging." http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs

Comment: enable your datagrid paging  to true.

Comment: Post your aspx source for the gridview here so we can help you out.

Comment: Have you changed the default `DataSourceMode="DataSet"`? if you set to DataReader, sorting and paging won't work.

Comment: @nux I've added the code above. Is the DataSourceMode to be set in the gridview or the sqldatasource?

Comment: @Nick I'm looking into that article now. Eventually I'll need to seperate the paging functionality into a seperate, fixed footer and hide the stock paging. Will that article help with that?

Comment: @steventnorris There's always the custom data pager.. I've only ever used it with the list view. To be honest I highly suggest you look into A) Building your own grid with custom paging or B) Using a third party control. The standard GridView in my opinion isn't a practical solution in the real world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rebind `GridView`:

```
private void BindData()
{
    SqlDataSource sqlData = new SqlDataSource("Hidden for security reasons");
    Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    dataTbl.DataSource = sqlData;
    dataTbl.DataBind();
    headerTbl.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
}

protected void dataTbl_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    dataTbl.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

In markup add to `GridView`:

```
OnPageIndexChanging="dataTbl_PageIndexChanging"
```

It should work.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Do I have to do a similar process for the sorting capabilities?

Comment: To be honest I didn't do sorting this way and I don't know, but probably yes. Maybe you will need to sort data before binding it, because I don't know if `GridView` does this by itself. Try it out :).

Comment: One more thing, I think that if you used `SqlDataSource` created in markup and bind `GridView` to it there instead of in code behind, you'd have sorting and paging "out of the box" without additional coding.

Comment: Hmmm... Well I'm trying to avoid doing much in markup. I'm a big fan of encapsulating as much as possible, so I'm trying to offload all functionality to the .cs scripts and use the HTML as a view template. I'll give the sorting bit a check though. Thanks again!